# How to view data in django from react front-end

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to be able to view data that comes from my react front-end and want to use the print function to display the results in python

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def testfunc(request):
     return JsonResponse(request,safe=False)
```

thanks in advances

Answer (score 0):

You can print `request.POST`, this is a `QueryDict` (a dictionary-like object that can contain *multiple* items for the same key):

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def testfunc(request):
    print(request.POST)
    return JsonResponse(dict(request.POST.lists()))
```